# Soccer Game only with National Team names (country names) what about player names?

Tags: licensing

Ok...this question hasn't been asked before, its very similar to some, but here's the difference:

I am making a soccer/football simulator game, that only has national teams (with no official logos) just the country names and flags.
Now, my doubt is the following...can I use real player names (that play or played on that national team?)

From what I understand if I use a player name linked to a club like Barcelona FC (not a national team) I need the right from the club and the association that club is linked to, right?
But If I am only linking the name just to a country...I might just need the permission of the actual player (that I am using his name) and not any other associations, correct?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Cheers,
Diego.

Comment: Let users name their own team/players. Problem Solved. Beyond that, I doubt you'd get permission from any players.

Comment: Talk to an actual lawyer.

Comment: I stumbled over this question by accident. Obviously this is not a duplicate and was closed by accident. The answer has 2 parts. First, yes you can use national flags and country names in a game, in all jurisdictions I know of, as long as the use of the name and flags are not putting the country in a bad light (and in some jurisdictions even then. Second, organizations like FIFA are still allowed to sue you even if what you did is perfectly legal. If they manage to get a sympathetic judge they might even win, or at least require you to spend quite a bit on an actual lawyer to defend your case.